# Excessive access constraints in queries (1C:Enterprise 8.3.17.1851)

Tags: erp

1C:Enterprise Platform: 8.3.17.1851

For a document, the record-level security (RLS) is configured. The document has a table section with additional attributes specified as the document's characteristics.

When rendering the document in a dynamic list with an additional attribute, the database server receives the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 45 T1.Ref
FROM dbo.Document.Document1 T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 (
  SELECT T11.Ref AS Q_001_F_000RRef,
  T11.Value AS Q_001_F_001RRef,
  T11.Value AS Q_001_F_002_TYPE,
  T11.Value AS Q_001_F_002_L,
  T11.Value AS Q_001_F_002_N,
  T11.Value AS Q_001_F_002_T,
  T11.Value AS Q_001_F_002_S,
  T11.Value AS Q_001_F_002_RTRef,
  T11.Value AS Q_001_F_002_RRRef 
  FROM dbo.Document.Document1.AdditionalAttributes T11 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Document.Document1 T12 ON T11.Ref = T12.Ref
  // query constraint description
)
// query constraint description
```

It turns out that the platform applies a query constraint to the main table several times.

For a non-trivial query constraint, this may result in significant query processing performance degradation. The more additional attributes you include in the query, the greater performance degradation you experience.

Why the platform cannot avoid adding excessive access constraints when applying the inner join or left outer join of the main table to the table section?

Answer (score 0):

In a general case, the construction
FROM dbo.Document.Document1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Document.Document1 T2 ON 
assumes that the system may select different records from T1 and T2.
So, the access constraints should be applied both to T1 and to T2 independently.
In certain cases, depending on the constraint types, the platform can optimize the query.
Probably, in the scenario you described, the query cannot be optimized.